# call Now() for each row during update statement execution

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

Is it possible to force the now() function (or something similar) to return the current value for each row as it updates?

As I understand it, normaly the function is only called one time as statement is executed and all rows get the same value.

Is it possible to change that behavior?

The DBMS is a DB2 on AS400 v5r2m0

Comment: What are you expecting to see, unless the insert is huge and slow, it's likely that now will be the same value for all inserts in the batch anyway. In the unlikely event I wanted to do this, I'd try putting a default on the column of Now() and not inserting the value.

Comment: I want to execute a single **Update** Statement which will change about 220000 rows. This statment needs 2-5 minutes to finish. Everyone of these changed rows should get its own timestamp describing the moment in which it was updated, not the moment the statement was parsed by the DBMS.

Comment: Like I said I'd try adding a default constraint to the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

*"Every time a row is added or changed in a table with a row change timestamp column, the row change timestamp column value is set to the timestamp corresponding to the time of the insert or update operation."*

*[...]*

*"When you create a table, you can define a column in the table to be a row change timestamp column."*

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/sqlp/rbafysqlprcts.htm

Comment: i'll give it a try ASAP

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot alter the Table in that way. So it doenst work for us.